# Selects fields from Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've got a fairly big RDD with 400 fields coming from Kafka spark stream, I need to create another RDD or Map by selecting some fields from initial RDD stream when I transform the stream and eventually writing the Elasticsearch.

I know my fields by field name but don't know the field index.

How do I project the specific fields by field name to a new Map?

Comment: You can try converting your entry into a Map and select what field you want or you can convert your RDD into a DataFrame and then select also which fields you want. Nevertheless, your question need more details and quite broad for that matter.

Comment: What kind of file are you reading from, and how are you creating the rdd?  @eliasah is right, we don't have enough information to really help you here.

Comment: @eliasah yeah, basically am reading data from Kakfa and transforming it to another RDD with more fields which I've done. The part am trying to just figure out is how to set the value of the new fields based on some other fields. I probably can solve it using a Map....am a newbie in Scala/Spark ;-)

Comment: You just have to remember that if you can apply a function on an entry in an RDD, you definitely can map it over the RDD. Check what I wrote about processing entries in a RDD [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149608/spark-sql-generate-array-of-arrays-from-the-sql-function/36152222#36152222) you might get the picture.

Comment: and please provide a (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] so we try to help further !

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming each field is delimited by delimiter '#'. You can determine the index for each field using the first row or header file and store in some data-structure. Subsequently, you can use this structure to determine the fields and create new maps.
2. You can use Apache Avro format to pre-process the data. That would allow you to access the data based on their fields and would not require the knowledge of their indexes in the String. The following link provides a great starting point to integrate Avro with Kafka and Spark.

http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/03/04/kafka-spark-avro-producing-and-consuming-avro-messages.html